# Longlist is not populated with items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm trying to populate the Longlist via WCF following [this tutorial](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth). I want to group users by their income (from min to max), but groups are displayed randomly. Also there are no items in the list (see picture below). What am I missing?
My XAML code is:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
    <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="usersHeaderTemplate">
        <Border Width="72" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" Margin="6">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Income}"
               FontSize="20" Padding="6"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="usersItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Flag}"  Height="50" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Income,StringFormat='Income: {0}'}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Job}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="LongListSelectorJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
        <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="113,113"/>
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"
                                    Width="113" Height="113" Margin="6" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                           FontSize="48" Padding="6"
                                           Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="usersListHeader">
        <Border Background="White" Opacity="0.2" Height="70">
            <TextBlock Text="List Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="usersListFooter">
        <Border Background="White" Opacity="0.2" Height="70">
            <TextBlock Text="List Footer" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longlist2" Height="608" Margin="10,15,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422"
IsGroupingEnabled="True" LayoutMode="List" HideEmptyGroups="False"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource usersItemTemplate}"
GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource usersHeaderTemplate}"
JumpListStyle="{StaticResource LongListSelectorJumpListStyle}"
ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource usersListHeader}"
ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource usersListFooter}" >
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My service implementation is:

```
public IEnumerable<mTeachers> GetStuffList(string Job)
    {
        List<mTeachers> stuffList = new List<mTeachers>();
        DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        List<mTeachers> finalList = new List<mTeachers>();
            foreach (var d in data.Stuffs)
            {
                stuffList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = d.stuffName, Income = (int)d.stuffIncome, Job = Job, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/users.png", UriKind.Relative) });               
            }
                return stuffList;              
    }
  private List<Group<mTeachers>> GetUsersGroups(string Job)
    {
        IEnumerable<mTeachers> usersList = GetStuffList(Job);
        return GetItemGroups(usersList, c => c.Income);
    }
    private static List<Group<T>> GetItemGroups<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList, Func<T, int> getKeyFunc)
    {
        IEnumerable<Group<T>> groupList = from item in itemList
                                                  group item by getKeyFunc(item) into g
                                                  orderby g.Key
                                                  select new Group<T>(g.Key, g);
        return groupList.ToList();
    }
    public class Group<T> : List<T>
    {
        public Group(int income, IEnumerable<T> items)
            : base(items)
        {
            this.Income = income;
        }

        public int Income
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

My service interface:

```
 [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<mTeachers> GetStuffList(string Job);
    }
[DataContract]
public class mTeachers
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Income { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Job { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public System.Uri Flag { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** WP page code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        proxy.GetStuffListCompleted += showList;
        proxy.GetStuffListAsync("teacher");
    }
    private void showList(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetStuffListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.longlist2.ItemsSource = e.Result; 
    }
```

[image: my screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to the LongListSelector declaration in your XAML. So it should look like this.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longlist2" Height="608" Margin="10,15,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="True" LayoutMode="List" HideEmptyGroups="False"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource usersItemTemplate}"
                        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource usersHeaderTemplate}"
                        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource LongListSelectorJumpListStyle}"
                        ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource usersListHeader}"
                        ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource usersListFooter}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things going on here.

First I think your GetStuffList(string Job) function is doing something weird, please check the return values to see if it's exactly what you want.

Second I think the ItemSource needs to be set like KasunKV said.

Here are my fixes and the resulting screenshot showing it works.

```
// create a static group list to see if it works
private List<Group<mTeachers>> GetUsersGroups(string Job)
{
    List<mTeachers> usersList = new List<mTeachers>();

    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Bob", Income = 1000, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative),  Job = "Guy" });
    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Dan", Income = 1000, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative), Job = "Guy" });
    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Kate", Income = 2000, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative), Job = "Girl" });
    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Charlie", Income = 2000, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative), Job = "Guy" });
    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Jeff", Income = 2000, Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative), Job = "Guy" });
    usersList.Add(new mTeachers() { Name = "Jeff2", Flag = new Uri(@"/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative), Job = "Guy" });
    return GetItemGroups(usersList, c => c.Income);
}


// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // create the user group and bind it to item source
    this.longlist2.ItemsSource = GetUsersGroups("whatever");
}
```

Results of the change can be view here:

[image]

Comment: GetStuffList(string Job) is working fine and retuns what I want. I checked it by adding simple longlist from the toolbox and just added those 3 binding values. It showed but didn't order items. But this more advanced XAML doesn't show items, even with added `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. It may be XAML problem. 
Also I want this list to be created dynamically in the WCF service. Static methods don't work for me.

Comment: If you want to create it dynamically you probably want to create the collection as an ObservableCollection this way any changes to the collection will reflect on the UI because it implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: changed my method to `ObservableCollection<mTeachers> GetStuffList(string Job)` and still I have no items. Maybe there is something wrong with XAML?

Comment: Can you edit the code to show how you're calling GetStuffList?  Plus the section where you set the longlist2.ItemSource = ..... ?

Comment: yes, did it. Did you have the same XAML code when you tested your static group list?

Comment: Yeah same XAML, without the ItemSource="{Binding}", I like to bind it manually.  If you take a look at my screenshot you will see it has the same headers and everything, it also orders it by income as well.  I don't  know why your data isn't working, it shouldn't matter if it is static or not.  For example, having a longlistselector bind to a RSS Feed.  It just needs to be in the correct format.